# Which Linux distro supports GNOME 3 by default?

Tags: linux, gnome3, user-interface

I was planning on installing a new Linux distribution and I am thinking of trying GNOME 3 interface. Other than Fedora 16 (which has GNOME 3 as default) which other distro supports it? I know it can be installed from the repository, but I tried the GNOME 3 on OpenSuse and had hard time running it; it never really integrated fully. So would be good to know what distro supports GNOME 3 seamlessly.

Any other distro than Fedora and Mint linux? (Not so keen on Mint so looking for others)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.gnome.org/getting-gnome/

> **Fedora**
>
> Just install or try it live to use GNOME 3.
>
> **openSUSE**
>
> GNOME 3.2 is the default desktop environment of openSUSE 12.1.
>
> **Mageia**
>
> GNOME 3 will be part of Mageia 2. Install ‘task-gnome’ after installing Mageia.
>
> **Arch Linux**
>
> Arch Linux has GNOME 3 in the extra repository.
>
> **Ubuntu**
>
> From Oneiric (11.10) onwards, GNOME is just a click away.
>
> **Debian**
>
> GNOME 3 is available from the wheezy/testing repository.